JS files not rendering in browser
We have uploaded a JS file to the HTML Design Package as a binary to Acme HTML Design component (Acme Publication > Building Blocks > Modules > Acme > Admin > Acme HTML Design).  The Publish HTML Design page was then published (Acme Publication > Home > _System > Publish HTML Design), with the expectation that the JS file would be written to the filesystem of web server.  On Dev environment this was tested successfully, but in Production the JS file is not being included in the publish transaction zip file.
Additional Details:

Implementation is using Tridion Sites 9.6, DXA 2.2 (.NET).
CM and CD microservices are hosted by RWS, web servers are hosted directly by customer.
Customer had published the js file successfully several years ago before upgrading to 9.6, this is the first time it has been attempted post-upgrade.
Developer added another JS file to the package and published, afterwards JS file is also written to web server.
There appear to be no differences between the Dev and Prod environments for the DXA configuration.
When Deployer cleanup was temporarily disabled, the JS file is not included in the publish transaction zip file.
The JS file is published successfully on Dev, and there are some minor changes to the JS file on the Prod environment.  When the Prod JS file is swapped in on the Dev environment HTML Design component, error is replicated there.  For a binary file, it's not clear why the different JS file would make a difference.

Is it possible to suggest what steps are necessary to resolve issue, ie publish the JS file to the Prod environment successfully?
